# Can web push be implemented, with only having control of a subdirectory of the domain?

Tags: web-development, notification

Our website is part of a bigger enterprise website and is located in a directory, eg.: domain.com/ourdir/.

We would like to implement web push notifications, using one of the many available software and services, but we do not have control over the domain, only the subdirectory. So we can not change name servers, install site-wide snippets, etc.

Is this possible, and if it is, which service would be most likely to work with my setup?

So far I tried one service, only to find out, that they require you to install a snippet on the whole domain.